# How to use firestore real time listeners with redux?

Tags: firebase, redux

I have a react redux project, I wanto to use the firebase firestore real time listener.

Right now I have an action that fetches the initial data:

```
export const handleInitialData = () => async dispatch => {
  const lists = await firestore.collection('lists').get()

  if (lists) {
    const resolvedLists = lists.docs.map(list => list.data())
    return dispatch(receiveLists(resolvedLists))    
  }
}
```

As you can see im using `.collection('lists').get()` and it works.

But i want to use the realtime listener by using `.onSnapshot` like this:

```
export const handleInitialData = () => async dispatch => {
  const lists = await firestore.collection('lists').onSnapshot(snapshop => {
   let changes = snapshop.docChanges()
  })
}
```

but If I do that i get the error:
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

I have no idea where to go from here... any tips on getting this working?

Ive seen there is this library `https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase`

But it uses `recompose` which I hate, plus is not recommened anymore by the author.

Would apretiate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working had to do this instead:

```
export const handleInitialData = () => async dispatch => {
  // const lists = await firestore.collection('lists').get()
  let docs
  const lists = await firestore.collection('lists').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    docs = snapshot.docChanges().map(c =>c.doc.data())
    if (docs) {
      return dispatch(receiveLists(docs))    
    }
    return
  })
}
```